# How to mock object creation for a singleton factory?

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock, powermockito

The example I tried to follow:

```
@PrepareForTest(X.class)
public class XTest extends PowerMockTestCase {
        @Test
        public void test() {
                whenNew(MyClass.class).withNoArguments().thenThrow(new IOException("error message"));

                X x = new X();
                x.y(); // y is the method doing "new MyClass()"

                ..
        }
}
```

The factory class I am trying to unit test:

```
public final class LoadableBeanFactory implements ILoadableBeanFactory {
    private static final class Loader {
        private static final LoadableBeanFactory INSTANCE = new LoadableBeanFactory();
    }

    private LoadableBeanFactory() { }

    public static @Nonnull LoadableBeanFactory getInstance() {
        return Loader.INSTANCE;
    }

    public final @Nonnull <BeanT extends ILoadableBean> BeanT create(final Class<BeanT> beanClass) {

       final BeanT optionBean;

        try {

            final Constructor<BeanT> ctor = beanClass.getConstructor();
            optionBean = ctor.newInstance();
            return beanClass.cast(optionBean);
        } catch(Exception e) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not instantiate an instance of " + beanClass);
        }
    }
}
```

My test is below. The factory does not return the mock. I am thinking that this is because the factory is a singleton that is instantiated and loaded with a private static loader class. So, is there a way to mock this object creation scenario or should I just give up on making this into a true unit test?

```
@PrepareForTest(LoadableBeanFactory.class)
@Test(groups = {"FactoryTestGroup", "LoadableBeanFactoryTestGroup"})
public class LoadableBeanFactoryTest extends PowerMockTestCase {

    @Mock LoadableBean mockBean;

    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldCreateBean() {
        try {

                PowerMockito.whenNew(LoadableBean.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockBean);
            LoadableBeanFactory.getInstance().create(LoadableBean.class);
        assertEquals(LoadableBeanFactory.getInstance().create(LoadableBean.class), mockBean,
                    "LoadableBeanFactory should have return mocked bean, but did not: " + mockBean);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            fail("Failed to mock bean creation");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is due to the factory instantiating your beans through reflection, and most likely has something to do with classloading, but I'm not familiar with these low level aspects of mockito/powermock. If you were simply returning a `new LoadableBean()` it would work. Small note, you can use `assertSame` to check that the arguments refer to the same instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you even want to do that?

If you wrap the factory in an abstraction (a separate class) then you can inject it via constructor and mock its create method.

```
public class BeanFactory {

public <BeanT extends ILoadableBean> BeanT create(final Class<BeanT> beanClass) {
return LoadableBeanFactory.getInstance().create(beanClass);
    }

}
```

and now your class that you want to work with

```
public class SomeClass {
private final BeanFactory beanFactory;

public SomeClass(BeanFactory beanFactory)  {
this.beanFactory= beanFactory;
}

public void doSth() {
beanFactory.create(...);
}

}
```

And then you don't need to have PowerMock at all and your design is really nice.

Comment: Great suggestion! I will be re-tooling my code base to use this design pattern for factories.